# Why does backtrace not contain Objective-C symbols regardless of -rdynamic?

Tags: objective-c, linux, gcc, stack-trace, glibc

**Update:** I'm working with the GNU-runtime on Linux. The problem does **not** occur on MacOS with the Apple-runtime.

**Update 2:** I compiled the GNU-runtime on MacOS and build the example with it. The error does **not** occur on MacOS with the GNU-runtime. I would say the problem is the glibc (since `backtrace` and `backtrace_symbols` are glibc extensions).

When printing a backtrace in a GCC compiled Objective-C app using `backtrace`and `backtrace_symbols`, I don't get any Objective-C symbols. Only the filenames, addresses and C-symbols appear.

I compiled with `-g` and linked with `-rdynamic`.

My test app:

```
void _printTrace()
{
    void *addr[1024];
    int aCount = backtrace(addr, 1024);
    char **frameStrings = backtrace_symbols(addr, aCount);
    for (int i = 0; i < aCount; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", frameStrings[i]);
    }
    free(frameStrings);
}

@interface TheObject
+ (void)_printTrace;
+ (void)printTrace;
@end

@implementation TheObject
+ (void)_printTrace
{
    _printTrace();
}

+ (void)printTrace
{
    [self _printTrace];
}
@end

void printTrace()
{
    [TheObject printTrace];
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printTrace();
    return 0;
}
```

and it's output:

```
./test.bin(_printTrace+0x1f) [0x8048e05]
./test.bin() [0x8048e60]
./test.bin() [0x8048e8b]
./test.bin(printTrace+0x34) [0x8048ec5]
./test.bin(main+0xf) [0x8048eda]
/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe5) [0xb7643bb5]
./test.bin() [0x8048b51]
```

Is there a way to let the Objective-C symbols appear in this backtrace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dladdr()` only reports global and weak symbols. But all Objective-C function symbols are local:

```
$ readelf -s so_backtrace

Symbol table '.dynsym' contains 29 entries:
…

Symbol table '.symtab' contains 121 entries:
   Num:    Value  Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
…
    49: 08048a01    13 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   14 _c_TheObject___printTrace
    50: 08048a0e    47 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   14 _c_TheObject__printTrace
…
```

You can verify that local symbols are never returned by looking at the [GNU libc source code](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=tree) yourself. `backtrace_symbols()` is defined in sysdeps/generic/elf/backtracesyms.c. It relies on `_dl_addr()`, which is defined in elf/dl-addr.c, to provide it with the symbol names. That ultimately calls `determine_info()`. If it can, it uses the the [GNU hash table](http://blogs.oracle.com/ali/entry/gnu_hash_elf_sections), which does not include local symbols by design:

```
49       /* We look at all symbol table entries referenced by the hash
50          table.  */
…
60                   /* The hash table never references local symbols so
61                      we can omit that test here.  */
```

If the GNU hash table isn't present, it falls back to standard hash table. This includes all the symbols, but the `determine_info()` code filters out all but the global symbols and weak symbols:

```
90         if ((ELFW(ST_BIND) (symtab->st_info) == STB_GLOBAL
91              || ELFW(ST_BIND) (symtab->st_info) == STB_WEAK)
```

To symbolicate the Objective-C function addresses, you would have to perform the look-up yourself and not filter out the local function symbols. Further, you would have to demangle the Objective-C function symbols to restore `_c_TheObject___printTrace` to `+[TheObject _printTrace]`.

Comment: Good answer but my app has to run with a standard glibc and I cannot copy&change the glibc code since some details (like the `l_map_start` member of the `link_map` struct are private).

Comment: To know why I accepted your answer but did not give you the bounty please read my comment to dreamlax's answer.

Answer (score 1):

GNUstep's `NSException` implementation doesn't use `backtrace`, instead it uses `libbfd` (binary file descriptor). I think the function that actually does the work is called `static void find_address`, which you can view [here](http://gnustep-base.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.20.1-1/NSException_8m-source.html). Using this trivial example, I get the results that follow.

```
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Test : NSObject {}
+ (void) test;
@end

@implementation Test
+ (void) test
{
    Class GSStackTrace = objc_getClass("GSStackTrace");

    id stack = [GSStackTrace currentStack];

    for (int i = 0; i < [stack frameCount]; i++)
    {
        NSLog (@"%@", [[stack frameAt:i] function]);
    }
}
@end

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    [Test test];

    [pool release];

    return 0;
}
```

Output (when compiled with debug symbols):

```
2010-10-18 14:14:46.188 a.out[29091] +[GSStackTrace currentStack]
2010-10-18 14:14:46.190 a.out[29091] +[Test test]
2010-10-18 14:14:46.190 a.out[29091] main
2010-10-18 14:14:46.190 a.out[29091] __libc_start_main
```

You may be able to pick apart `GSStackTrace`. It is a “private” class (that's why I need to use `objc_getClass`, you'll also get lots of unrecognised selector warnings), but it seems to contain all the code necessary to read Objective-C class names.

Tested on Ubuntu 9.04 with GNUstep configured with `--enable-debug` (so that `GSFunctionInfo` is included in the build).

Comment: You won the bounty because your answer led me to an implementation for useful stacktraces without high level 3rd party libraries (like GNUStep ;)). But I will accept Jeremy's answer because I made the fault to ask two questions: 1. Why does the stacktrace does not include Obj-C symbols and 2. How can I have a stacktrace with Obj-C symbols. Obviously I started the bounty to get an answer to the second question. But the first one was the headline and so I will accept Jeremy's answer.

Answer (score -1):

I expect you'll need to ask the ObjC run time about the addresses to get symbol information. The addresses returned from backtrace() could probably be passed to something like object_getClass() to get the class, for example. I haven't tried any of this but it's where I'd look next in this case.

Comment: Woah that seems very speculative to me. `backtrace` (and `backtrace_symbols`) are glibc extensions where the latter relies on symbols linked in by the linker `-rdynamic`. I would be surprised if the addresses returned by `backtrace` are good for anything with the Objective-C runtime but I will try it nevertheless.

Comment: Okay, I looked up the runtime API. I am using the GNU runtime and I did not found a function for getting the class or the method of a symbol address. In the GNU runtime there is no `object_getClass()` but an `object_get_class()` which gets an object. But I am very sure, that the addresses of `backtrace` are not pointing to objects.

Comment: And now I'm sure: the addresses of `backtrace` are __neither__ objects __nor__ classes.

Comment: If I had known you were using the GNU runtime I wouldn't have answered, because I have no idea what is or is not available there. You should have made this clear from the start. I could make other suggestions but not ones that would be relevant to your environment.

Comment: Hmm, I  don't think that the runtime does matter. Nevertheless I will try the example on Mac today and if it does work there, I will clarify the question.

Comment: Okay, finally I got it compiled on MacOS (what a mess…). And it works there. I will clarify the question.