# in objective-c can I access the calling classname/methodname within a method?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nslog

in objective-c can I access the calling classname/methodname within a method?

Background:

I am currently putting the following line in some of my methods for logging:

```
NSLog(@"<%@:%@:%d>", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), __LINE__);
```

It would be nice to also include the class name and method name(location) of the code that called the method.

Is this possible?  What would the code be for this?

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding where a method was called from.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614208/finding-where-a-method-was-called-from)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no practical way to do this (hence all the methods in Cocoa with `sender` arguments). There isn't even a guarantee that there *is* such a thing — it could be called from a plain old, `self`-less function, or it could have been called from a method that was inlined into its calling method, or we could have got to that line from a jump, or….

Comment: The sender arguments have nothing to do with the lack of ability to deduce the sender.  In the original AppKit implwmtation, the self of the calling stack frame was easily available.  Sender is all about clarity of API.

Comment: @bbum - I guess you're implying it's no longer available in the current implementation?

Comment: That is correct;  beyond the debugging frameworks, which aren't 100% accurate, there is no way to do what you ask.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just doing this in the context of a debugging executable, consider trying the GDB Backtrace function:

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Backtraces.html

Not sure what that will end up looking like for Objective-C, but if you go back up the chain long enough you should find something invoking a message...

Or try reading through this and see if it helps at all:

[Why does backtrace not contain Objective-C symbols regardless of -rdynamic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719350/why-does-backtrace-not-contain-objective-c-symbols-regardless-of-rdynamic)

Answer (score 1):

http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/debugging/the-evolution-of-a-replacement-for-nslog

little googling can go long way :)

I use **PRETTY_FUNCTION** and DLog.

Comment: looks like the class/method for where you're calling the code from no? not the calling class/method that I was asking about

Comment: Yep, greg sorry misunderstood the question.